# AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'copy' - while trying to get object list in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

To practice my Django skills i try to make simple module that should work more or less like Admin site in Django. It should gather all Models from Application, list them and show every object from each Model. i try to do is using Django Rest Framework.

Here is my views.py. I have 2 views. The api_root listens all models but it also sends params-models_names to another view 'model_view'. The ModelViewSet should list all objects from particular model.

```
class ModelsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_name = '{model_name}Serializer'.format(
            model_name=self.kwargs.get('name').split(".")[1]
        )
        return getattr(serializers, serializer_name)

    def get_model(self):
        """methods return model based on name kwargs

        :return:
        """
        return apps.get_model(self.kwargs.get('name'))

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))


@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response([reverse(
             viewname='model_view',
             kwargs={'name': i._meta.label}) for i in apps.get_models()])
```

Here is my serializers.py. In this file serializers classes are dynamically build. Each class is built on the basis of the model from django.apps.

```
from django.apps import apps
from rest_framework import serializers
from admin_site import serializers as m
from . import models


app_models = apps.get_models()

for item in app_models:

    name = "{}Serializer".format(item.__name__)

    class Meta(type):
        model = item
        fields = '__all__'

    m.__dict__[name] = type(name, (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {})
    m.__dict__[name].__metaclass__ = Meta
```

And finally here is my my_app.urls.py file. I think that maybe the problem is that ModelSetView isn't registered using DefaultRouter() but on the other hand i need to pass param to urlpattern. I don't know

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.api_root),
    url(r'^model/(?P<name>[\w\-\.]+)/$',
        views.ModelsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'put':'update'}), name='model_view'),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

]

Everything is fine when i'm on api_root, i can see list of models. But when i add to root url  /model/auth.User/ i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 716, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, 
renderer_context)
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 650, in get_context
    raw_data_put_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'PUT', 
request)
  File "/home/wojjak/Projects/envs/taskenvv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 565, in get_raw_data_form
    data = serializer.data.copy()
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Any clue what can i do to accomplish my task and avoid this error?

Answer (score 11):

override `get_serializer_class()` not `get_serializer()`